# How can I show that if $f = g-h$ , $g\ge0$ and $h\ge0$ then $ f^+\le g $ and $ f^-\le h$

Tags: functions, inequality

Note that: $f^+ = \max\{f,0\}$ and $f^- = -\min\{f,0\}$.

I am thinking that to prove $f^+$, I'll use the fact that $f\le g$ and $g\ge 0$. But how about $f^-$?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

We can write as the following:
$$f^-=\begin{cases}0,\quad g\ge h\\h-g,\quad g<h\end{cases}$$
With both cases we see $f^-\le h$.